# Conditional formatting will not accept any formula

Tags: excel, vba

I'm programmatically adding conditional formatting and getting an

> error 5 invalid procedure call or argument

on the line where I'm setting the `FormatCondition` object to the variable `cf`:

```
Sub SetRCCF(ws As Worksheet, cf As FormatCondition, cFormula As String, cellColor As Variant, appliesToRange As range)

Set cf = ws.Cells.FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, formula1:=cFormula)
cf.Interior.color = cellColor
cf.ModifyAppliesToRange appliesToRange

End Sub
```

The `cf` is just sent by the calling method to reduce garbage collection.

An example of the formulas I'm using:

```
Dim f as String
f = "=AND($F1=" & Chr(34) & "FFR Dynamic - BM" & Chr(34) & ", $D1<>" & Chr(34) & "" & Chr(34) & ")"
```

However, I've tested with simple ones like `"=A1=TRUE"` with the same result.

I tested manually with the same result. A picture paints a thousand words:

[image]

I've checked the formulas for special characters and I've tried manually typing them in. I've tried on a different workbook. I've tried setting `cf` to `nothing` each call. There is no protection, not that that should matter.

This has not happened before and just started today. What is going on here?

Comment: You haven't unknowingly changed your regional settings recently such that you now require the semicolon as argument separator in formulas, instead of the comma?

Comment: Could it be that, by any reason, settings in your file are now F1C1 notation in formulas instead of A1 notation? try to do an easy formula in a cell, something like =A1 and see if it works

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - Bingo. Thanks very much. Now I feel silly.... :D